# Some permissions questions regarding userdir and usr/local/bin

Tags: permissions, home-directory

I've enabled userdir for Apache2, and I want to serve files from var/www symlinked to directories within my /home directory (i.e. /home/code/web) - but I need to extend permissions for that folder on account of it being within my home directory. Is it better to add all folders on the path to www-data, or make a folder at / and symlink it from my /home/code/web directory?

I've got a similar issue installing phantomjs - in that I'm keeping the lib in /home/code/libs/js and using a symlink from /usr/local/bin - but again when I try to execute the binary I get a permissions warning. I assume this is the same issue, in that I do not have permission to execute files within my home directory? Should I extend permissions on my homedir, or just keep these files in separate directories and link to there from my home dir?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps bind options of mount command helps:

```
# mount -o bind,rw /home/code/web /var/www
```